# what should be the name parameter while building database?

Tags: android, database, android-room

there are 3 parameters added while building Room Database -> Context, Database Class, Name of database

i am asking about the third parameter does it match with something or what??

Comment: since the database resides on a file system, you have to give some name to it. It's just for reference

Comment: means we can give any name right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a name that you want to give to your database file. Database file with such name will be stored inside internal storage available for your application. So it's simply a name that you want to associate with your database.

For example, if the database is intended to store general data you could name it just `AppDB`. If you create this database to store local users of your app it could be named `UsersDB` so that it is obvious what kind of data will be stored inside. It can be any name you prefer.